# Unknown type from inner function will not resolve to string in outer function

Tags: typescript

I have two functions:  `func1()` and `func2()`

`func1()` is called inside `func2`. The return value from `func1()` is returned as `func2()`'s return value.

```
func2() {
   return func1()
}
```

`func1()` has a return type of

```
interface Func1 {
  [key: string]: unknown
}
```

`func2()` has a return type of

```
interface Func2 {
   my_key: string; 
}
```

`func2()` is complaining that the return value of `func1()` does not contain the key `my_key`. To my eyes, there is a key that is a `string`. The `unknown` value should work with a more specific `string`. This apparently is not true.

Is there a way to fix this without list every key needed in `func2()`'s return value? `func1` is used inside many different functions with many different, more specific return types. I need it to be very general.

Answer (score 1):

no, you can't fix this without list the key you need in this case.

a possible solution is let `Func1` extends `Func2`:

```js
interface Func1 extends Func2 {
  [key: string]: unknown
}
```

but the logic of `func1` and `func2` may be incorrect. You need to provide more details if this solution not make sense in your code.

**some details:**

the key `[key: string]` means **there are some keys that is string** but not ensure **there is a key named `my_key`**

the `unknown` value can not assign to any "known" types like `string`, `number` ..., if you want to disable all type checks, you should use `any` instead of `unknown`.